# Return to same view after pressing home button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I am in someViewController, I press the iPhone home button and it takes me to the iPhone home screen. Then I re-enter my app by tapping its icon. It does not take me to the view where I left. Instead, it takes me to homeViewController which is first view of my app.

How do I make it so that the user will be returned to the view that they left, rather than the initial view controller?

Comment: A few things you need to check:

1) Has UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend been enabled?
2) How do you handle when applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationDidEnterBackground are called?

Comment: I did not enable UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend method.How do i enable it?

Comment: have u written exit(0)

Comment: No application kill itself until it is having instance. May be you are killing your app yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "info" in Xcode project and check into supported interface orientations.
If its having Application does not run in background is YES then do it NO. It will then take you to the same controller from where you left. 
Have a look on the screen shot below

[image]

Comment: for some reason i keep it as YES.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No I think there is no other way to do this because if it is NO then only instance of your app run in background thread, So you have to do it NO if you want to come on the same view controller. May I know the reason for which you have kept it YES????